# Interfaces and Classes between Projects

Tags: c#, interface

My application's structure looks like this:

Solution: MySolution

Projects in MySolution: Host, Business, Server.

References between the projects looks like this:

```
Host <-- Business --> Server
```

(Business references Host and Server but Host does not reference Server and vice versa because this causes a circular-)

So, I have some Database stuff in Server. I have a property, `DBConnectionString` - which should contain the connection string. What I want to do is to set this property from the Host but I want to keep all methods that have anything to do with the database in the Server project.

Keeping interfaces in mind - so that I can also at a later stage just create an web application.

I have some code and it's working but I don't know if this is the right way.

I have this interface in Library (connection between the other two projects):

```
    public interface IDBUtils
    {
        string DBConnectionString { get; set; }

        bool OpenConnection();

        bool CloseConnection();

        bool ExecuteSQL(string sql);

        bool CreateDatabase(string servername, string databaseName, string databaseDataPath);

        bool CreateDatabaseUser(string servername, string username, string password);
    }
```

Then the class in Library that has the code for the interface:

```
public string DBConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return DBService.DB.DBUtils.DBConnectionString;
    }
    set
    {
        DBService.DB.DBUtils.DBConnectionString = value;
    }
}

public bool OpenConnection()
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.OpenConnection();
}

public bool CloseConnection()
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.CloseConnection();
}

public bool ExecuteSQL(string sql)
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.ExecuteSQL(sql);
}

public bool CreateDatabase(string servername, string databaseName, string databaseDataPath)
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.CreateDatabase(servername, databaseName, databaseDataPath);
}

public bool CreateDatabaseUser(string servername, string username, string password)
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.CreateDatabaseUser(servername, username, password);
}
```

I'm only going to show the property and one method on the server otherwise this is going to get too long.

On the Server:
Property:

```
public static string DBConnectionString { get; set; }
```

The OpenCOnnection() Method:

```
        public static bool OpenConnection()
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (DBConnectionString.Length > 0)
                {
                    conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch { /* Do nothing... */ }
            return success;
        }
```

To set the property from Host on Server:

It uses the interface on Library:

```
iDBUtils.DBConnectionString = connectionString.ToString();
```

To execute a method from Host on Server:

```
iDBUtils.OpenConnection();
```

So as you can see, Library is the "Middle Man".

Comment: What about having a Data layer that is your db layer and using a config file for the connection string?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what about the methods then?

Comment: Also, If I put the connection string in the config file, will a company like be able to connect to a central server without going and editing the file? The app is basically on its own and not manual editing is done at the moment.

Comment: That depends on how your db server is setup, network paths etc. But if you have an application that is non-environment dependant (i.e., you can run it from basically any workstation) then it shouldnt be a problem, and keeping your connection string in a config file is preferred.

Comment: So it's 4 projects then? What's the direction of dependencies between Library and the rest? Imo Business shouldn't depend on anyone, not on the UI, not on the data.

Comment: Is the `Catch { /* do nothing */ }` really swallowing everything that could go wrong with opening a connection? Imo that method should either succeed or blow up with something more meaningful than a `false`...

Comment: An aside from the question, but I would refactor DBService.DB.DBUtils to implement the interface with instance methods (since it appears to have all the implementation code anyways) and then optionally create a singleton reference for the DBUtils class if you still really want a static means of accessing it.  Then you wouldn't need an instance class wrapper for it.

Comment: WARNING! `string`s can be null. Calling a method on a null reference is, well, `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Naming**

`IDBUtils` is a name for a namespace, but for an interface representing a database system it is poorly named. Better use something like `IDatabase`, `IDatabaseServer` or `IDatabaseSystem`.

**OpenConnection()**

This method can be simplified by removing the `success` variable and also using a guard clause, which reduces horizontal spacing.

```
public static bool OpenConnection()
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DBConnectionString.Length))
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch { /* Do nothing... */ }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining local variables where the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This looks cleaner and saves time when it comes to changing types during refactoring.

e.g.

```
bool success = false;
```

should be

```
var success = false;
```

**Validation**

You should validate the arguments to your public methods, any of those strings could be null or empty.